# Redirect assemblies in Mono?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, mono, assemblies

I have recently discovered that I am affected by this bug http://www.mail-archive.com/mono-bugs@lists.ximian.com/msg71515.html

Well, at http://www.mail-archive.com/mono-bugs@lists.ximian.com/msg71529.html they say the work around is to create a global policy assembly and redirect the assemblies that way since it is not read from the web.config.

How do you actually do what they describe there? There is a huge documentation gap in that area with Mono.

Also, I can't just recompile the assembly to use the new Mono assembly versions because the assembly is closed source. (but it does work with Mono.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the bug is now being fixed.. so soon it will be irrelevant http://www.mail-archive.com/mono-bugs@lists.ximian.com/msg71638.html